# Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ io_write

Tags: ruby

I have a piece of Ruby code that grabs a zip file from S3 and saves it locally.

```
File.open(local_filename, 'wb') { |file| file.write(body) }
```

This code works on some files but not others.

For the ones that don't work I get this error:

> Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ io_write - /path/to/file.zip

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: _"What could be the reason for this?"_ – the filename could be invalid, what does `p local_filename` return?

Comment: Maybe the place you're trying to write to doesn't exist or you don't have permissions.

Answer (score 4):

The body might be too huge. The error message indeed doesn't make much sense, but it's a possible cause.

---

To mitigate this, write it in smaller chunks. The simplest (though not the fastest) way is going character by character:

```
File.open('file_name.txt', 'wb') do |file|
  body.each_char { |char| file.write char }
end
```

Comment: This is indeed correct, but, like you mentioned, definitely not the fastest. I've added an answer with some other options, including benchmarks comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `StringIO` and `.read( chunk_size )`.

@ndnenkov is absolutely correct. The file itself may be too big to store in memory. This limit varies from system to system, based on OS, config and available resources.

However, using `each_char` can be extremely slow for very large files. I benchmarked a few methods and chunk sizes with a few different file sizes for comparison.

```
13027836 bytes
13.03 megabytes
                           user     system      total        real
write:                 0.000767   0.004443   0.005210 (  0.005312)
each_char:             5.756789   0.032231   5.789020 (  5.797378)
each_byte:             8.997680   0.067377   9.065057 (  9.179755)
StringIO 1 KB:         0.004029   0.006966   0.010995 (  0.011648)
StringIO 1 MB:         0.016100   0.007118   0.023218 (  0.023509)
StringIO 10 MB:        0.003347   0.006924   0.010271 (  0.010334)
StringIO 100 MB:       0.000456   0.003758   0.004214 (  0.007080)
StringIO 1 GB:         0.000468   0.003787   0.004255 (  0.005037)


706583272 bytes
0.71 gigabytes
                           user     system      total        real
write:                 0.001035   0.285726   0.286761 (  0.324529)
each_char:           362.444086   1.820033 364.264119 (365.362415)
each_byte:           548.788409   3.254867 552.043276 (553.390843)
StringIO 1 KB:         0.310588   0.331768   0.642356 (  0.697581)
StringIO 1 MB:         0.302101   0.325285   0.627386 (  0.671933)
StringIO 10 MB:        0.254845   0.294017   0.548862 (  0.895430)
StringIO 100 MB:       0.471879   0.429933   0.901812 (  1.181456)
StringIO 1 GB:         0.000471   0.260011   0.260482 (  0.653977)


5577825775 bytes
5.58 gigabytes
                            user     system       total         real
write:                     error      error       error        error
each_char:           2926.215017  38.658114 2964.873131 (3008.319599)
each_byte:           4305.082576  35.090730 4340.173306 (4363.944091)
StringIO 1 KB:          4.145908   3.962275    8.108183 (   9.490059)
StringIO 1 MB:          3.741062   2.779802    6.520864 (   7.423770)
StringIO 10 MB:         2.916272   2.553926    5.470198 (   6.271349)
StringIO 100 MB:        4.262794   3.007702    7.270496 (  10.986725)
StringIO 1 GB:          2.063459   4.572225    6.635684 (   9.212933)
```

Based on this, we ended up using `StringIO` with a chunk size of 1MB, but you'll want to experiment with your specific situation:

```rb
File.open('file_name.txt', 'wb') do |file|
  bodyIO = StringIO.new( body )
  until bodyIO.eof?
    file.write( bodyIO.read( 1024*1024 ) ) # Write 1 MB chunks at a time to avoid Errno::EINVAL errors like `Invalid argument @ io_fread` and `Invalid argument @ io_write`.
  end
end
```